# Allocating matrix performances

Tags: c, performance, matrix, calloc

I have two scenarios, in both i allocate 78*2 sizeof(int) of memory and initialize it to 0.
Are there any differences regards performances?

Scenario A:

```
int ** v = calloc(2 , sizeof(int*));

    for (i=0; i<2; ++i)
    {
        v[i] = calloc(78, sizeof(int));
    }
```

Scenario B:

```
int ** v = calloc(78 , sizeof(int*));

    for (i=0; i<78; ++i)
    {
        v[i] = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
    }
```

I supposed that in performance terms, it's better to use a calloc if an initialize array is needed, let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: Each allocation has some overhead. Therefore my hunch is that 78 allocations of 2 elements (the 2nd case) will be slower than 2 allocations of 78 elements (the 1st case). But with performance issues the best advise is that you should measure it yourself.

Comment: Since you fill the array of pointers with real values right away, the first `calloc` could just as well be a `malloc`. The choice between A and B depends on what you actually want. Do you want your data organized as 2x78 or 78x2?

Comment: Further to what Thomas Jager said: the efficiency you probably care more about will be the efficiency of actually *using* the data in this array, not just allocating it.  So in choosing 2x78 versus 78x2, you want to consider the loops you'll have for traversing the arrays.  For good [*locality of reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) (i.e. cache performance), you'll want the innermost loop to traverse contiguously-allocated memory (typically a "row").

Comment: Also, the "ragged" arrays you're allocating, with their pointers to pointers, are usually not maximally efficient.  For the absolutely best performance, you'll ideally want a more "true" array — which means that if you don't know the size at compile time, you can use a VLA ("variable-length array").  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465).

Comment: Why not allocate a true 2d array in a single allocation? Case A: `int (*v)[72] = calloc(2, sizeof *v);`. Case B: `int (*v)[2] = calloc(78, sizeof *v);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, discussing optimization abstractly has some difficulties because compilers are becoming increasingly better at optimization. (For some reason, compiler developers will not stop improving them.) We do not always know what machine code given source code will produce, especially when we write source code today and expect it to be used for many years to come. Optimization may consolidate multiple steps into one or may omit unnecessary steps (such as clearing memory with `calloc` instead of `malloc` immediately before the memory is completely overwritten in a `for` loop). There is a growing difference between what source code nominally says (“Do these specific steps in this specific order”) and what it technically says in the language abstraction (“Compute the same results as this source code in some optimized fashion”).

However, we can generally figure that writing source code without unnecessary steps is at least as good as writing source code with unnecessary steps. With that in mind, let’s consider the nominal steps in your scenarios.

In Scenario A, we tell the computer:

- Allocate 2 `int *`, clear them, and put their address in `v`.
- Twice, allocate 78 `int`, clear them, and put their addresses in the preceding `int *`.

In Scenario B, we tell the computer:

- Allocate 78 `int *`, clear them, and put their address in `v`.
- 78 times, allocate two `int`, clear them, and put their addresses in the preceding `int *`.

We can easily see two things:

- Both of these scenarios both clear the memory for the `int *` and immediately fill it with other data. That is wasteful; there is no need to set memory to zero before setting it to something else. Just set it to something else. Use `malloc` for this, not `calloc`. `malloc` takes just one parameter for the size instead of two that are multiplied, so replace `calloc(2, sizeof (int *))` with `malloc(2 * sizeof (int *))`. (Also, to tie the allocation to the pointer being assigned, use `int **v = malloc(2 * sizeof *v);` instead of repeating the type separately.)
- At the step where Scenario B does 78 things, Scenario A does two things, but the code is otherwise very similar, so Scenario A has fewer steps. If both would serve some purpose, then A is likely preferable.

However, both scenarios allude to another issue. Presumably, the so-called array will be used later in the program, likely in a form like `v[i][j]`. Using this as a value means:

- Fetch the pointer `v`.
- Calculate `i` elements beyond that.
- Fetch the pointer at that location.
- Calculate `j` elements beyond that.
- Fetch the `int` at that location.

Let’s consider a different way to define `v`: `int (*v)[78] = malloc(2 * sizeof *v);`.

This says:

- Allocate space for 2 arrays of 78 `int` and put their address in `v`.

Immediately we see that involves fewer steps than Scenario A or Scenario B. But also look at what it does to the steps for using `v[i][j]` as a value. Because `v` is a pointer to an array instead of a pointer to a pointer, the computer can calculate where the appropriate element is instead of having to load an address from memory:

- Fetch the pointer `v`.
- Calculate `i`•78 elements beyond that.
- Calculate `j` elements beyond that.
- Fetch the `int` at that location.

So this pointer-to-array version is one step fewer than the pointer-to-pointer version.

Further, the pointer-to-pointer version requires an additional fetch from memory for each use of `v[i][j]`. Fetches from memory can be expensive relative to in-processor operations like multiplying and adding, so it is a good step to eliminate. Having to fetch a pointer can prevent a processor from predicting where the next load from memory might be based on recent patterns of use. Additionally, the pointer-to-array version puts all the elements of the 2×78 array together in memory, which can benefit the cache performance. Processors are also designed for efficient use of consecutive memory. With the pointer-to-pointer version, the separate allocations typically wind up with at least some separation between the rows and may have a lot of separation, which can break the benefits of consecutive memory use.